# Need Help Updating Info in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to save a profile image using Parse as a PFFile. Basically, the current user gets to pick the image and the image should be saved in Profile class under profilePic for me to retrieve later. The code runs with no error but the image is not updating in Parse. It still has the original profile placeholder image that I set for that user at LogIn instead of the new image that was selected. I'm new to Swift and Parse. If you need anything else to answer the question please let me know. This is the code I have in my imagePickerController:

```
          self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    ProfileImage.image = image
    let profilePicData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImage.image)
    let profilePicFile = PFFile(name: "imageProfile.png", data: profilePicData)


    var query = PFQuery(className: "Profile")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( objects, error) -> Void in

        if let objects = objects {

            for object in objects{

                var username = object["username"] as! String
                var id = object["userId"] as! String
                var profilePic = object["profilePic"] as! PFFile

                if id == PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId{

                    profilePic = profilePicFile

                    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success, error) -> Void in

                        if(error == nil)
                        {
                            println("success")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: You should add a `whereKey` clause to your query to select userId=currentUser.  Then you wouldn't need to iterate through all of the returned objects.  Your current approach is inefficient and will fail once you have more than 1000 users

Comment: If I use the whereKey and put    query.whereKey("userId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId) then the error is value of optional type String? is not unwrapped

Comment: You rarely need to use .objectId with Parse. You can just use the PFObject directly - you need to unwrap `PFObject.currentUser` - add an ! To it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#files

> Finally, after the save completes, you can associate a PFFile onto a PFObject just like any other piece of data:

you have to save the PFFile before you assign it to the object. Indeed, as Icaro pointed out, you have to assign the picture direct to the object

```
ProfileImage.image = image
let profilePicData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ProfileImage.image)
let profilePicFile = PFFile(name: "imageProfile.png", data: profilePicData)


var query = PFQuery(className: "Profile")

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ ( objects, error) -> Void in

    if(error == nil) {
        let profiles = (objects as? [PFObject]) ?? []
        for profile in profiles{

            var username = profile["username"] as! String
            var id = profile["userId"] as! String
            var profilePic = profile["profilePic"] as! PFFile

            if id == PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId{
               profilePicFile.save() //I would recommend you to do a save in background
               profile["profilePic"] = profilePicFile

                profile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success, error) -> Void in

                    if(error == nil)
                    {
                        println("success")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: I tried that but it won't build successfully because of the error message "Cannot assign a value of type 'PFFile' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!" which occurs at the line `object["profilePic"] = profilePicFile`

Comment: I have edit my answer. It should work now because I unwrapped the profiles as PFObjects

Comment: Thanks,  it works now. I didn't know that the profiles should be unwrapped as PFObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Swift does not use reference for the variable profilePic so when you updat it you are not updating your object, you need to update your object variable that you are using to save, as below:

```
                var profilePic = object["profilePic"] as! PFFile

                if id == PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId{

                    // profilePic = profilePicFile - change this
                    object["profilePic"] = profilePicFile // for this

                    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{(success, error) -> Void in

                        if(error == nil)
                        {
                            println("success")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still won't work! The error message says that I "Cannot assign a value of type 'PFFile' to a value of type 'AnyObject?!"